DNS resolution does not work in K8s pod with CoreDNS service IP but works with CoreDNS pod IP
I have a single node K8s cluster running on a Ubuntu 22.04 machine, and I launched the cluster from K8s source code with the following command:
sudo CGROUP_DRIVER=systemd KUBELET_RESOLV_CONF=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf hack/local-up-cluster.sh -O

I created a test pod with kubectl -it test --image=busybox sh and then ran nslookup to test DNS resolution, but it failed:
# nslookup github.com 
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

But if I edit the test pod's /etc/resolv.conf and change the nameserver from CoreDNS service IP (10.0.0.10) to CoreDNS pod IP (10.88.0.17), nslookup works well.
# nslookup github.com 
Server:         10.88.0.17
Address:        10.88.0.17:53

Name:   github.com
Address: 20.205.243.166

Then I ran tcpdump -i eth0 udp -n -vvv in the test pod to capture UDP packets. I found when the nameserver in the test pod's /etc/resolv.conf is CoreDNS pod IP, the output of tcpdump is like the below when I run nslookup github.com:
16:53:35.770523 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 9938, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    10.88.0.18.44975 > 10.88.0.17.53: [bad udp cksum 0x1508 -> 0x9a15!] 38162+ A? github.com. (28)
16:53:35.770547 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 9939, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    10.88.0.18.44975 > 10.88.0.17.53: [bad udp cksum 0x1508 -> 0x7209!] 48387+ AAAA? github.com. (28)
16:53:35.775474 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23546, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 82)
    10.88.0.17.53 > 10.88.0.18.44975: [bad udp cksum 0x1522 -> 0x021d!] 38162* q: A? github.com. 1/0/0 github.com. [5s] A 20.205.243.166 (54)
16:53:35.776274 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23547, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    10.88.0.17.53 > 10.88.0.18.44975: [bad udp cksum 0x1508 -> 0xed88!] 48387* q: AAAA? github.com. 0/0/0 (28)

But when the nameserver in the test pod's /etc/resolv.conf is CoreDNS service IP, the output of tcpdump is like the below when I run nslookup github.com
16:54:39.579380 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62369, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    10.88.0.18.39260 > 10.0.0.10.53: [bad udp cksum 0x14a9 -> 0x9cdc!] 43261+ A? github.com. (28)
16:54:39.579459 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62370, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    10.88.0.18.39260 > 10.0.0.10.53: [bad udp cksum 0x14a9 -> 0x8fef!] 46543+ AAAA? github.com. (28)
16:54:39.590595 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31294, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 82)
    10.88.0.17.53 > 10.88.0.18.39260: [bad udp cksum 0x1522 -> 0x0485!] 43261* q: A? github.com. 1/0/0 github.com. [5s] A 20.205.243.166 (54)
16:54:39.590927 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31295, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    10.88.0.17.53 > 10.88.0.18.39260: [bad udp cksum 0x1508 -> 0x0b10!] 46543* q: AAAA? github.com. 0/0/0 (28)
16:54:42.082230 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62371, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    10.88.0.18.39260 > 10.0.0.10.53: [bad udp cksum 0x14a9 -> 0x9cdc!] 43261+ A? github.com. (28)
16:54:42.082318 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62372, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    10.88.0.18.39260 > 10.0.0.10.53: [bad udp cksum 0x14a9 -> 0x8fef!] 46543+ AAAA? github.com. (28)
16:54:42.082720 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31749, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    10.88.0.17.53 > 10.88.0.18.39260: [bad udp cksum 0x1508 -> 0x0b10!] 46543* q: AAAA? github.com. 0/0/0 (28)
16:54:42.082784 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31750, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 82)
    10.88.0.17.53 > 10.88.0.18.39260: [bad udp cksum 0x1522 -> 0x0487!] 43261* q: A? github.com. 1/0/0 github.com. [3s] A 20.205.243.166 (54)

Can anyone please let me know why the pod DNS resolution fails with CoreDNS service IP as its nameserver?

Scale down your CoreDNS pods to one, and then launch two pods: one on the same node as the CoreDNS pod, and one on another node. If your pod, which is co-located on the same node as the CoreDNS pod, is able to resolve DNS queries despite having checksum errors while the other pod is not, then it's probably your CNI. In my case some necessary ports for Cilium were not open, so I had to tell the OpenStack admin to open them, and the problem was resolved. Search for all the required open ports for Cilium (or any other CNI). I think, the reason is that the Linux kernel allows packets to go through the loopback interface even if the checksum is wrong, but it drops the packets for other interfaces. Not sure, tho.

What I have is a single node K8s cluster.
